# SQLSRV to Excel using php - Missing zero's in data cells

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I am using **SQLSRV** to download the data from server to excel based on requirement
When i display the data its fine, but when i try to download using 
`header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel")` the leading zero in the integer are missing.

For example '*0012346*' gets converted into '*12346*'.
**In my results file i need leading zeros also like  - '*0012346*'.**

How can i achieve it?

Comment: Assuming that you're generating a CSV file, check the file that you're creating in a text editor rather than by opening it in MS Excel, because Excel will not apply leading zeroes when it imports a CSV file.... simply setting a header does not convert a file into a native-format Excel file automatically

Comment: That's how numbers work: leading zeroes are redundant and can be removed. Just stop handling your data as number. Can you please edit the question, say what Excel library you are using and share the relevant code?